# All Inboxes in Mail app showing only five messages

Tags: iphone, ios, email

Despite the fact that I have tons of mail, the All Inboxes page today displays five messages only. Whereas when looking into the individual mailboxes the problem is eliminated.

[image]

I've tried restarting and quitting the mail app but nothing worked out.

Comment: The problem could be that, you have tons of mails. Try a restart

Comment: Try changing network. And can you remove the mail account with most emails and readd  it if others appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the email account within the Mail App

1. Go to **Settings** > **Passwords & Accounts** > **Accounts**

   - Or Settings > Mail ( or Mail, Contacts, Calendars) > Accounts
2. Select the mail account that shows the incorrect unread mail notifications

   - If you have more than one, perform these steps for each account
3. Toggle OFF “Mail” to disable it. *This action does not delete your account*

[image]

4. Exit Settings by returning to your Home Screen
5. Close the Mail app by swiping up your Gesture Bar or by pressing the Home button twice. Locate the Mail app preview and swipe up to close it
6. Now once again go to **Settings** > **Passwords & Accounts** > **Accounts**

   - For older iOS, go to Settings >Mail (Mail, Contacts, Calendars) and select the mail account
7. Toggle ON Mail to enable it.
8. Check to see if your mail app is now showing the correct unread email counts.